# Does Bluemix have elastic search functionality?

Tags: ibm-cloud

IBM Bluemix is based on Cloud Foundry. Does Bluemix provide elastic search? If not, what is alternate solution? It seems Cloudant, which is based on CouchDB, provides similar functionality, but does it allow to persist word / pdf documents or only json? How do we convert word/pdf to json? Basically, we require all flexibility on Bluemix as offered by Solr text search - ability to save/query word/pdf documents..

Answer (score 2):

IBM also offers Databases for Elasticsearch, which is the next generation of their Compose offering - https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/databases-for-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

IBM Bluemix does not offer a managed Elasticsearch service in the catalogue.

It is possible to run your own Elasticsearch server on the platform [using Docker](http://jamesthom.as/blog/2015/07/08/making-logs-awesome-with-elasticsearch-and-docker/).

CouchDB does allow the user to store any associated data blobs as [*attachments* to JSON documents](https://docs.cloudant.com/attachments.html). However, the indexing of this content will be left to the application developer.

Answer (score 0):

IBM bought Compose a few days ago, and as a result the Bluemix catalog now has ElasticSearch available, via the Compose service.

For more info, check out https://console.ng.bluemix.net/solutions/data-analytics

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix offers the [ElasticSearch by Compose](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/elasticsearch-by-compose/) service